# Incorrect syntax near keyword 'desc'

Tags: c#, mysql

**help me please. I don't know what went wrong.** It's saying that I have an incorrect syntax near the keyword 'desc' but I don't see anything wrong with this one.

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        pbMainImage.Image.Save(ms, pbMainImage.Image.RawFormat)
        Dim sql As String = "insert into contestants(lName,fName,mName,age,gender,address,college,desc,const_num,image_main) values(@lname,@fname,@mname,@age,@gender,@address,@college,@descr,@num,@image)"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, constring)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbLName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbFName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbMName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(tbAge.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@gender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbGender.SelectedItem
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbAddr.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@college", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cmbDept.SelectedItem
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@descr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbDesc.Text.Trim()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@num", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(tbNumber.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ms.ToArray()

        OpenConnection()


        Try
            cmd.Connection = constring
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            constring.Close()

            MsgBox("Added New Contestant.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error at " & ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

Comment: Hint 1: look at the column names in your INSERT clause. Hint 2: look up a list of SQL reserved words.

Comment: **help me please**  There is lots of help here.  There is the [help], but also [ask] and the [tour] for new users

Comment: if you are using key words / reserved words in your sql query's wrap them around `[desc]` because the word `desc` is reserved for `Descending`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`desc` is a reserved keyword - it means "descending" in `order by` clauses. So: you need to escape that column to `[desc]` or `"desc"` (depending on the database) to tell it you mean the column name.

Comment: @jeffbu no, I'm not saying *change* the column name; escaping / quoting in a sql operation just makes it very explicit to the parser that you *mean* a column named *desc*, rather than the reserved word

Comment: so i should only replace desc with 'desc' I'll try .

Comment: I mean. Changing the column name is not practical. but isn't it the "cleaner" way of coding as I am not violating any reserved words?

Comment: Read the comments @jeffbu if you are not sure about sql do yourself a simple google search also read up about column `aliasing` in SQL plenty of free online tutorials for basic SQL

Comment: Change the column name to `description` - it'll save a lot of headache in the future. Do not call column names the same as any sql reserved word

Comment: thank you man. I finally was able to add a new record. A great new knowledge. I'm always using "desc" for description because it was not a reserved keyword in some of my previous works but now that I'm using MySql. I should take not of this. great help man.

Comment: @CaiusJard meh... they add new keywords (contextual or reserved) every version... IMO it is more practical to learn how to deal with it :)

Comment: @marcgravell maybe, but for two points: new versions are rare, and keywords typically make for crap names anyway as they're rather bland. Calling a column "datetime" or "Boolean" is nigh on useless

Answer (score 1):

You are using a keyword for a column name so it must be quoted. But, based on your parameter name, you probably meant `descr` instead of `desc`, anyway.

Comment: no i used descr as parameter so I could find where the error is.

Comment: do you mean to say i need to do it like this? 'desc', 'const_num' so on and so forth?